# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type from assembly

Tags: asp.net

Today I've started having this annoying issue while trying to run my web application.

The scenario is as follows:

I have a Web Application Project (WAP from now on) and 4 Library Projects (BusinessEntities, BusinessLogic, DataAccess and Utils).

DataAccess references BusinessEntities
BusinessLogic references BusinessEntities and DataAccess
The WAP references BusinessLogic, BusinessEntities and DataAccess

When I run the WAP I get:

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Namespace.DataAccess.ClassDataAccess' from assembly 'DataAccessAssembly', Version=1.0.3551.29465, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

This is when a method from BusinessLogic tries to create an isntance of a DataAccess class. I use reflector on the DataAccess dll inside de bin folder of the WAP and it does contain the class I'm calling.

I've already tried deleting temporary asp.net file but without success, I'm using Cassini as web server (did not tried IIS yet)

Thanks.

Comment: any solution about it ?

Comment: In my case I renamed my namespace name. It was same as external dll namespace which I referenced to my project.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a tool that comes with the SDK called [fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx).  It is useful for finding assembly binding errors and explains why the error occurred.

Comment: Use this tool! It will save you a lot of frustration :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a debug tool. I was facing a problem running an app with Mono on Linux, looked for "fuslogvw.exe" on the net and found (this page)[http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/assembly-bind-tracking-td1505796.html], where they say you can see debug messages by setting environment variables `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=info` and `MONO_LOG_MASK=asm`.

Comment: This tool is great.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that you've got some mixed up version numbers in your references.

Check your project references, your web.config file and your .dll versions to make sure that all your references are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved a similar problem (TypeLoadException with null InnerException for a class from a dll that appears to be there). Reason was that we were referencing *client* dll from a *server* project (ie. Foo.DomainService.dll instead of Foo.DomainService.Web.dll).

Answer (score -1):

You need to check the InnerException for the root cause